# Updating to GIT 2.0.1

Tags: centos, redhat, git

I had installed git 2.0.1 compiled from source. It worked well.

```
# cd git-2.0.1
# make prefix=/usr/local/git all
# make prefix=/usr/local/git install
# echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin" >> /etc/bashrc
# source /etc/bashrc

#git --version showed 2.0.1
```

Now when I installed Developer Tools

yum install "Development Tools"

It installed git 1.7.1. 
My path variable is:

```
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/data/softwares/git
```

I againg tried to install git 2.0.1 but it alwasy shows1.7.1. How to change git to latest version install and remove old git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a look at the blog [here](http://akyl.net/how-install-latest-version-git-centos-63) I found the solution in one of the comments. Make sure you got the rpmforge repository added to your CentOS (Reference: [How to add RPMFORGE repo to CentOS](http://geek-kb.com/linux/install-rpmforge-repository/)) yum and just run the following command:

```
yum --disablerepo=base,updates --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras install git
```

If you already have git installed then use:

```
yum --disablerepo=base,updates --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras update git
```

Comment: `Error getting repository data for rpmforge-extras, repository not found`